# tkinter .pack()

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola estoy intentando hacer una interfaz gráfica para visualización de datos, pero estoy teniendo problemas con la función `.pack()` de tkinter, en el momento que intento "colocar" el `frame` dentro de la raíz deja de funcionar todo.
Concretamente en la linea de "texto".
¿Cuál sería el uso correcto de esta función para que todo se quede encuadrado?
Si suprimo la línea `texto.pack()` si funciona la interfaz, pero obviamente no se ve nada.

Dejo aquí las líneas de codigo.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as FileDialog
from io import open
from tkintertable.Tables import TableCanvas
from tkintertable.TableModels import TableModel

#----------------------------Raíz------------------------------------------------------------------

# Configuración de la raíz
root = Tk()
root.title('Visualización de datos mediante validación de ejes radiales.')
root.configure(bg = 'black')
root.iconbitmap('fibonacci.ico')
miFrame=Frame(root)

#---------------------Caja de texto introducción variables (izqrd)-----------------------------------
texto = Text()
texto=Entry(miFrame, textvariable=texto)
texto.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
texto.pack(fill="none")#, expand=10)
texto.config(font=("Arial",12))

#------------------------Caja de gráficos (derecha)---------------------------------------------------

Grafica=StringVar()

Grafica=Entry(miFrame, textvariable=Grafica)
Grafica.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
Grafica.config(background="black", fg="#03f943", justify="right")

#----------------------Monitor inferior--------------------------------------------------------------
mensaje = StringVar()
mensaje.set("Bienvenido al visualizador de variables.")
monitor = Label(root, textvar=mensaje, bg='black', fg='white')
#monitor.insert(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2,sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)
monitor.pack(side="left")

root.config(menu=menubar)


# Finalmente bucle de la apliación
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No puedes usar grid y pack en el mismo widget padre, es incongruente.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta configurar las posiciones de tus entradas y textos utilizando la opcion `.place` de python

```python
texto = Label(text='Hola')
texto.place(x=10, y=25)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
root = Tk()
miFrame=Frame(root)

texto = Text()
texto=Entry(miFrame )
texto.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
texto.pack(fill="none")#, expand=10)
##### ERROR: usar dos tipos de admintradores de widgets sobre un mismo widget

Grafica=Entry(miFrame, textvariable=Grafica)
Grafica.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
###### correcion: se debe usar el mismo administrador de widget para todos los widgets de un mismo Frame
```

Grafica usa grid y texto usa grid pero tambien place, esto no debe ser asi

solucion especifica: usar para los widget entry guardado en grafica y texto que tenga por maestro miFrame el mismo administrador de widget

solucion general: usar para todo widget que tenga por maestro el mismo frame el mismo administrador de widget